# How can I access params in next navigation

Tags: typescript, react-native

I work with Typescript and I have simple navigation:

```
function go_to_screen(rout_name:string,device_model:string){

  avis_instance.save_data('main_model', device_model);
  navigation.navigate(rout_name,{ name: device_model });

}
```

and then, on the next navigation I cannot access to name param via:

```
route.params.name or params.name ...
```

How can do this? Thanks!

P.S:
here is component in next view : I generated it  via default init expo .
you can see what and how access to it .
do you have any idea ?

```
export default function BottomTabNavigator() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="TabOne"
      tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: Colors[colorScheme].tint }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name=" "
        component={TabOneNavigator}
        
      />
    
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}

const TabOneStack = createStackNavigator<TabOneParamList>();

function TabOneNavigator() {
  console.log("moziii"+route.params.name );
  return (
    <TabOneStack.Navigator>
      <TabOneStack.Screen
        name="TabOneScreen"
        component={TabOneScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: 'Anik' ,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#034ea2',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
      
      }}
      />
    </TabOneStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you please share the code of the component where you are trying to access params

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are not passing any props to your `TabOneNavigator`.

Here is an example code for accessing params. Notice how it is passing `route` and `navigation` as props. And then it has access to the `route` prop.

```js
function DetailsScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  /* 2. Get the param */
  const { itemId, otherParam } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
      <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details... again"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.push('Details', {
            itemId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
          })
        }
      />
      <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

P.S. and here is a note from the docs

> It is recommended that the params you pass are JSON-serializable. That way, you'll be able to use state persistence and your screen components will have the right contract for implementing deep linking.

Comment: Thank you. , I got access the param in BottomTabNavigator() , but how to pass it to TabOneNavigator() , I just wnat to update the title bu I can't pass the value to it ..

Comment: try something like this.

``` react
component={<TabOneNavigator {...props} />}
```
This will pass all the props to the ```TabOneNavigator```. Also, I think this will be a good read for you https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html